# Setting up a fastapi web application

Tags: python, web, fastapi, cpanel

I need help o how to set up a python and fastApi web application in cPanel of some server. Please help!I tried everything and couldn't find out the way to do it. I need help in just setting it up and running on web, the app is done and the frontend of the app too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "tried everything" entail? It's hard for someone else to know what that "everything" is, and how you tried deploying it. Commonly FastAPI is deployed using gunicorn, but there are other options available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114261/is-there-a-way-to-deploy-a-fastapi-app-on-cpanel - see also https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/ - you might also have luck deploying it as a container instead, as that's a standardized way of deploying applications these days.